# after function not working, no error given

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a nutshell, I'm trying to have an input generated, with a label created after the fact. However, instead of the expected label html being created, no label is shown, no errors show up in jsfiddle (although it doesn't work there either), and no error is presented when executing the code. Not even anything in the developer console in chrome. Here's the code snippet that I'm using to attempt this.

```
fieldset.append($('<input/>').attr({ type: 'radio', name: 'category', value: key, id: key}).click( function() { highLightButton("selected", key);  hideShowText("show"); }).after("<label for='" + key + "'>AAA</label>"));
```

Am I binding it incorrectly? Perhaps a separate append call needs to be made? From what examples I've seen it should work, and yet it seems to just ignore the code.

jsFiddle URL as requested

http://jsfiddle.net/bL7heuoc/

Comment: may you post your jsfiddle url? if fieldset is an empty jquery collection, by example, nothing is going to happen.

Comment: @cesarpachon URl provided, and no it has content as I can see the html for the input items created within the fieldset, just no labels created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var $input = $('<input/>');

$input.attr({
    type: 'radio',
    name: 'category',
    value: 'abc',
    id: '123'
}).click(function (e) {
    console.log('click');
});

$('body').append($input);

$input.after("<label for='123'>AAA</label>");
```

**JSFiddle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sz29u00s/**

Answer (score 1):

@Jim is right, basically for "after" to work you need that the element has a parent (that at the end is where the new element will be added). that is why it works when you first append to the DOM and then call the after method.

Comment: And that would be why with the current setup it wouldn't work. Makes sense.